# If statement not returning the desired result

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement, mysql-connector

I'm new to Python and I believe the issue with my code is being caused by the fact that I'm a newbie and there's some theory or something that I must not be familiar with yet.

Yes, this question was asked before but, is different from mine. Believe me I tried everything that I thought that needs to be done.

Everything worked until I added everything in "if five in silos" statement.
After I enter the values for the 6 input functions, the program just finishes with exit code 0. Nothing else happens. The for loop is not initiated.

I want for the code to accept either 103 or 106 when prompting to enter something for the "five" variable.

I'm using PyCharm and Python 3.7.

```py
import mysql.connector

try:
    db = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="",
        user="",
        passwd="",
        database=""
    )

    one = int(input("Number of requested telephone numbers: "))
    two = input("Enter the prefix (4 characters) with a leading 0: ")[:4]
    three = int(input("Enter the ccid: "))
    four = int(input("Enter the cid: "))
    six = input("Enter case number: ")
    five = int(input("Enter silo (103, 106 only): "))

    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM n1 WHERE ddi LIKE '{two}%' AND silo = 1 AND ccid = 0 LIMIT {one}")
    cursor.fetchall()

    silos = (103, 106)

    if five in silos:
        if cursor.rowcount > 0:
            for row in cursor:
                seven = input(f"{row[1]} has been found on our system. Do you want to continue? Type either Y or N.")
                if seven == "Y":
                    cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO n{five} (ddi, silo, ccid, campaign, assigned, allocated, "
                                   f"internal_notes, client_notes, agentid, carrier, alias) VALUES "
                                   f"('{row[1]}', 1, {three}, {four}, NOW(), NOW(), 'This is a test.', '', 0, "
                                   f"'{row[13]}', '') "
                                   f"ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE "
                                   f"silo = VALUES (silo), "
                                   f"ccid = VALUES (ccid), "
                                   f"campaign = VALUES (campaign);")
                    cursor.execute(f"UPDATE n1 SET silo = {five}, internal_notes = '{six}', allocated = NOW() WHERE "
                                   f"ddi = '{row[1]}'")
                else:
                    print("The operation has been canceled.")
            db.commit()
        else:
            print(f"No results for prefix {two}.")
    else:
        print("Enter either silo 103 or 106.")

        cursor.close()
        db.close()

except (ValueError, NameError):
    print("Please, enter an integer for all questions, except case number.")
```

Comment: Don't you want: `silos = range(103,106)`  and `if five in silos`. Or defining `silos` as a list if you only want 103 and 106? `silos = [103,106]`

Comment: @CeliusStingher - Thanks for the response. As far as I know, range looks for values between 103 and 106 (104, 105 as well), what I am trying to do there is to have only 2 values that can be used when entering something. Or am I doing it the wrong way?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with  `if five in silos:` statement. Use breakpoint after the statement and go step by step in debug mode to check what happens.

Comment: @makozaki - I'm using the debugger but it doesn't work. If I put the red bullet next to "seven = input(f"{row[1]} has been fou[...]" it just finishes and doesn't display anything. It's like I'm running the entire code normally, not debugging it.

Comment: @makozaki - Tested both if statements and both work if I put a value that's not accepted, and concluded the issue is with the "for" statement. Do you guys notice anything wrong with it? Thank you!

Comment: It's like "for row in cursor" is not getting any data at all. Is this because is placed within 2 if statements?

Comment: just add following print statement befoire the if statement in question.
`print("five is", repr(five))`

add also `print("rowcount", cursor.rowcount)` before the related if statement

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem: I had to store `cursor.fetchall()` into a variable.
After I put: `eight = cursor.fetchall()` before the "silos" tuple, everything worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Because it must be:

```
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    // do something
```

In your code `cursor` returns a Python Class defined by `db.cursor()` but you need to call the `fetchall()` function to read the rows contained in it.

You're actually calling `cursor.fetchall()` without doing nothing with it, you can assign the call to a variable and than do this:

```
result = cursor.fetchall()
for row in result:
   //do something
```